# What is the function of the modifier keys in xmodmap?

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, xmodmap, xkb

When I run xmodmap, I get something like this

```
shift       shift_l (0x32),  shift_r (0x3e)
lock      
control     control_l (0x25),  control_l (0x42),  control_r (0x69)
mod1        alt_l (0x40),  alt_r (0x6c),  meta_l (0xcd)
mod2        num_lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        super_l (0x85),  super_r (0x86),  super_l (0xce),  hyper_l (0xcf)
mod5        iso_level3_shift (0x5c),  mode_switch (0xcb)
```

I get the shift and control groups. But what are the other mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4 for?

It seems that you can only use two modifiers as follows anyway:

```
keysym <keysymname> = <key> <shift+key> <mode_switch+key> <mode_switch+shift+key>
```

Why can't I set something to `<mod4+key>`?

Comment: I'd love to know how to set `<mod2+key>`... Did you find a way through yet?

Comment: No luck :( probably have to wade through code or find a responsive IRC channel. I just use my window manager to manage shortcuts now

Answer (score 3):

X11 provides 8 modifiers to any keypress.  You seem to have a fairly conventional set, where `shift`, `control` and `lock` have the obvious mappings.

`mod1` usually represents <kbd>Meta</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and `mod2` to `mod5` are available for whatever other modifier keys your keyboard has, often labelled <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Hyper</kbd>.  Usually these are not used for entering characters, but are interpreted by applications - for instance, in Emacs, I make <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> equivalent to <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```lisp
(define-key function-key-map (read-kbd-macro "s-<tab>") (read-kbd-macro "ESC TAB"))
```

If you want your keyboard to generate characters using these modifiers, then `xmodmap` is not really capable enough, and you'll want to look into `setxkbmap` instead.  That's a topic that's too big for this answer, though.